# How can I simplify or resample a Bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

When I use the Grease Pencil to draw out quick curves in the 3D Viewport, and then convert the pencil to a Bezier curve, the result is always consisting of very dense geometry and handles which are not aligned very well:

too many control points:

[image: dense sampling]

strange concept of handle alignment

[image: arbitrary normals]

Is there a Tool / Addon which can simplify these curves, so they become more smooth, and easier to control afterwards?

Comment: There is an addon called simplify curves, you can search for it in settings, the only problem with it that you need to change the curve shape back to 3D before exiting the edit mode.

Comment: @Denis thanks Denis, found it a few minutes ago, but feel free to post this as an answer, explaining a bit more in depth what the options are. I'm happy to mark it as answered then, the solution works for me.

Comment: Convert to mesh and limited dissolve... and come back to curve

Comment: @lemon interesting approach. After doing both, setting the limiting angle to something high like 15 degrees, and converting back, I do not see any more curve handles, everything became kind of sharp. Am I missing an option?

Comment: @aliasguru, no I think you are not missing an option. You may set the curve to bezier and the handles to auto. But effectively, in some cases, the result stays sharp. So this way is ok, but not "all the time".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simplify the curves with an addon called **Simplify Curves** that can be found and enabled in the settings.

When the addon is enabled you need to select the curve that you want to simplify, then hit <kbd>Space bar</kbd> button and type *simplify curves* in the search field.

[image]

Once you selected the function, by bringing operator menu with <kbd>F6</kbd> button or in the operator panel you will be able to change the amount of smoothing.

[image]

Once you get the desired result, change the **Shape** of the curve to **3D** in the Curve Settings panel.

[image]

**Original:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]