# How to simplify or resample a Bezier curve in Blender 2.9?

Tags: bezier-curves

I searched in the forum and saw [the other post of the same question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61428/how-can-i-simplify-or-resample-a-bezier-curve) posted 4 years ago, tried to follow it but found I couldn't do it in 2.9.

So I created a path and converted it to mesh. Exit the Edit Mode, with the curve selected, I hit F3 to search for Simplify Curves. By applying it to the curve, it gives me an error message:Failed to find '3D Viewport: Add (Shift A) ▶ Curve ▶ Curve Simplify'

Is there a different way to do it in 2.9?

Comment: simplify curve doesn't work on *mesh objects*. Once you converted the curve to mesh, you can no longer use simplify curve on that object. It is not a curve anymore...

Comment: plus, Curve SImplify is an addon, you need to activate it, is it your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following gif:

[image]

---

Here I have simply added a curve object, and then used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>>*simplify curve* and then repeated the process with anew curve and an intermediate step of converting the curve to mesh.

As you can see, the option for simplify curve is unavailable with the new mesh object, as the operator is only usable for *curve objects*. So, in your situation, either convert back to curve, or add a new object if it is not too tedious of a task.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_curve/simplify_curves.html#simplify-curves) for the *Simplify Curves* add-on.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But the problem is I want to make a plane out of the curve, is there a way to not having so many vertices after I convert the curve to mesh?